# Tamanho máximo de QRcode

Tags: qrcode

Estou implementando em um projeto um leitor e gerador de QRcodes e me veio a dúvida, até quanto tempo um QRcode pode armazenar?

Eu conseguiria algo em torno de 3 páginas de texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, você quer saber a quantidade de armazenamento que um QRCODE pode conter? se sim

1. Numérica - máx. 7089 caracteres
2. Alfanumérica - máx. 4296 caracteres
3. Binário (8 bits) - máx. 2953 bytes
4. Kanji/Kana - máx. 1817 caracteres